# What is the best way to use wcf client ? (memory wise)

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

I have read about the memory usage of a wcf client and what i have done until now is might be wrong.
When i have used a wcf client, i created a new wcf client for each call. (for self hosting and for iis).
is it the way to go ? of i should create one client as a member and use it all around ?
what is the truly memory usage of a wcf client ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you actually having memory issues here? If so: are you disposing them?

Comment: well, yes i had memory issues and i fixed them by loosing the `using` statement and disposing of them properly, i wanted to know what is the more expensive part of creating a client the `ChannelFactory` or the `ChannelFactory.CreateChannel()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that you should only create a new client when you need to call service operations from a new endpoint, but your binding typically stays the same. So you can a create a factory class to make clients for a specific contract + binding but different endpoints. For example, the following would be for WebHttpBinding but you can substitute whatever binding you need:

```
public class WebHttpClient<T> 
{
    protected WebHttpBinding Binding { get; private set; }

    public WebHttpClient()
    {
        // set default binding here
    }

    public WebHttpClient(WebHttpBinding binding)
    {
        Binding = binding; 
    }

    public T Get(string uri)
    {
        EndpointAddress _endpoint = new EndpointAddress(uri);
        ChannelFactory<T> _factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(Binding, _endpoint);

        _factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        return _factory.CreateChannel();
    }
}
```

Where T is your service contract.

Comment: Meaning if you already created a client for a specific binding the factory will return the created client ?

Comment: Everytime you call the method Get above it will return an instance of the implementation of your service contract at the specified endpoint. Theres a bunch of different routes to go but that basic formula of using ChannelFactory<T> is best for creating clients, I think.

Comment: The most expensive part of the WCF operation (as I understand it) is creating the client.  The above example is good, but I would take it one step further and call ChannelFactory<T> one time for each service and cache that, and then when creating a channel do it from the cached copy.  That way you can generate multiple channels but only incur the initial cost once.